# How can i activate emacs-binding in doom emacs?

Tags: spacemacs, doom

I am using doom emacs. But I want traditional emacs key binding. I've heard several people that emacs key binding becomes way of life and if somebody takes my key binding away, I cant express myself.

Please give me way to use emacs binding in doom.
Also
after adding emacs binding, please tell me how can i add it to home like showing all binding instead of evil ones.

Comment: I don't use doom. Does `C-z` work? It's supposed to toggle between emacs/evil for `evil-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doom.d/init.el disable loading of evil and do the usual "doom sync". This way the evil module is not loaded and keybindings are "back to normal".